# How reload or refresh page when session has expired with Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

Good morning!

We are implementing session control for our app, we need to reload page automatically to go to login page when session expires or show a modal or pop-up to make user know that the session has expired and take user to login page, we have tried a lot of options to make it, but anything works for us.

This is our context:

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :prepare_session

def prepare_session

 if !session[:expiry_time].nil? and session[:expiry_time] < Time.now
   # Session has expired. Clear the current session.
   deny_access 'Your session has timed out. Please log back in.'
 end

 # Assign a new expiry time, whether the session has expired or not.
 session[:expiry_time] = 1.minutes.from_now
 return true
end
```

**session_helper.rb**

```
def deny_access(msg = nil)
 msg ||= 'Please sign in to access this page.'
 flash[:notice] ||= msg
 redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'login'
end
```

and inside deny_access method after flash message, we have `redirect_to` and our login function controller, but it just do that in background, and ruby console give us this log

**RubyMine log**

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/login
Filter chain halted as :prepare_session rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-06 11:28:06 -0500
Processing by UsersController#login as JSON
  Rendered users/login.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1089ms (Views: 1087.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Despite the message telling us that view *users/login.html.erb* have been redirected, nothing happens in our app, just until we reload page manually, so, these are all options that we have tried:

**redirect_to:**

```
redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'login'
redirect_to url_for(:controller => :users, :action => :login)
redirect_to 'users/login'
redirect_to :back
redirect_to root_url 
redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])
```

**respond_to:**

for this test, we created a *redirect_to_login.js.erb* file inside */views/users/* that file contains a `window.location.reload()`, but It never arrives to that file, therefore, our page is never reloaded

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html{
    redirect_to 'users/login'
  }
  format.js {
    render 'users/redirect_to_login', :layout=>false
  }
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js {
    render nothing: true
  }
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
end
```

Any suggestions what's going on? or what should we do? We are going to be grateful for help

greetings!

Comment: It looks like the request was for JSON. Maybe that request is actually done with ajax?

Comment: Just a quick question - should your whole app be protected this way? Or you have any other pages that you don't want to perform "auto-logout" *mechanism*?

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu thank you for asking and yes, we are trying to reload page through ajax request but it is not working

Comment: @PawełDawczak thank you for asking, our whole page have "auto-logout" mechanism, It is because we have session expire time and no matter where the user is, if session expire, it should take user to login page automatically, Do you have any suggestions? It could be a big help

Comment: Well, I have some idea, but let me create an example project on my own, and I'll get back to you with *something*. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I've understood you must implement some mechanism to redirect to the login page after any ajax request with an expired session.

I would start to have a respond_to version for JSON and let the client know the session is expired.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    redirect_to 'users/login'
  }
  format.json {
    render json: {error: 'session_expired'}
  }
end
```

At the client side you must intercept those errors. One easy way to do that would be to use http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete (assuming here that you are using jQuery).

It would look something like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if(settings.dataType == "json") {
    var data = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    if(data && data.error && data.error == 'session_expired') {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this out so you might need to do some tweaking.